# WordPress 3.1 not compatible with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: permalinks, jquery, mobile

I recently updated to WordPress 3.1, and with that update, something very interesting happened. Links became unclickable -- clicking on any link would literally result in nothing happening. Interestingly enough, all of the jQuery stuff still works. Removing the jQuery Mobile script gets rid of the problem. The error being generated was:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://......./wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4 :: anonymous :: line 138"  data: no]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Anu, the answers I've gotten have either not ended up working or weren't what I was looking for. Do you think I should still accept an answer?

Comment: well in most of those cases you haven't gone back and commented or responded to work through to an answer.

Comment: Not true. Check again.

Comment: I did check, anyway, just offering some advice on how to get better responses from more people, so good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but your error message indicates that WordPress is using jQuery 1.4.4. If you look at the jQuery Mobile website, they're using 1.5. Have you tried using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to use a jQuery 1.5? You'd want to try something like:

```
<?php
function my_init_method() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}    

add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I've already tried that. When I use 1.5, no error appears in the Firefox console -- links just don't work without any warning.